# Rotate my arrow when reaching the final contact section?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, animation

I am working on this website: [demo](http://kickads.mobi/prueba/examples/PRUEBA.html)

I have a fixed scroll down arrow in a website in the right corner, and I want to rotate this arrow so it points to the top when the user scrolls down to the last section, and when you scroll up, it returns to its original rotation. I have tried doing it with some JS I found on the internet, but I couldn´t make it work.

Can anyone help me with this? It can be with JS or JQuery also.

This is my code:

```css
.center-con2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    bottom: 17px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

.round2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 40px;   
}

#cta2{
    width:100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
  <div class="center-con2">
    <div class="round2">
        <div id="cta2">
        <a style="color: #18a8a4" href="#!"><i id="icon" style="font-size: 20px" class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#theTarget').position().top){
        flipTheImageHere();
    }
})
```

I would use a jQuery function like this, detect when you scroll to a ID and when you're there flip it, otherwise flip it back.

Comment: So, if I paste this code to my website, I should change the ID `#theTarget` with the ID of the contact section?

Comment: To an extent yes, throw that in your javascript, give your website section an ID and replace thetarget in the javascript with that ID. The inside the function you need to flip the image which you can do with CSS, or jquery, and just add an else statement to the if to flip it back.